# window.open from site A to site B and back again

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my situation:

- Site A has a link to Site B
- Site A & B are in different domains
- Site A sets it's window.name property to "A"
- Site A's link to Site B has a target="B" property in the link
- Site B tries to do a window.open to site A with the "A" as the target (2nd parm)
- In IE and FF, site A doesn't open in the same window but creates a new window/tab, works in Chrome.

I think this has to do with the domain.  Because in our DEV environment, the above scenario works for IE (still not for FF) since the port is the only difference in the URL.  In the TEST environment, the URLs have different domains.

Anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: Makes no sense to me? `target="B"`, really? The browser settings determines wether or not to open in a new window or not, there are things you can do to suggest to the browser that it should be a new window, but there's no certain way to open something in a new window, that's up to the user/browser.

Comment: Different domains can't access each other's windows, that would be a security violation.

Comment: @adeneo, Can you site your sources for your comment? Everything I've been reading says that you should use target="B" to name the window you open so that you can get back to it.

Comment: @Barmar, I'm not trying to access the window, just open it w/o creating a new tab/window.

Comment: You're trying to replace the contents of a window that belongs to a different domain.

Comment: Then why does it work in Chrome?

Comment: Really, naming the window with the target attribute? I always thought `_blank`, `_self`, `_top` etc made more sense, but whatever ?

Comment: @Barmar Strictly speaking, this is not a security violation, since no data is exchanged. Still I'm not surprised it doesn't work. "Tabs" are not part of any standard that I've ever heard being mentioned. If there is no standard, browsers can do what they want. And what they want tends to be different.

Comment: There are many different types of security violations, they don't only involve data exchange. Allowing domain B to interfere with the operation of a page in domain A is another type of violation.

Comment: @adeneo Yes, you can set windows as `target`. From personal experience with trying to POST forms to windows... there's a lot of cross-browser manure you have to consider to get it mostly working.

Comment: @Barmar ...sounds reasonable

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `window.postMessage`. It seems like a better channel for what you are trying to achieve. At least in the case where you control the content of both domains. More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Comment: I'm not trying to send a message to the existing window, I'm trying to open it in a way that if it exists, I find it, otherwise, I open a new window.

Comment: With `window.postMessage` you can send a message from "B" to "A", telling it to open a different page. I thought this was your problem.

Comment: B doesn't have a reference to A to send the message.

Comment: And window.postMessage doesn't work for IE8 except for frames...which I don't use.

Comment: I was thinking `window.parent`, but actually it's for iframes. Not what you want to hear, but maybe you should use a modal dialog with an iframe instead?

Comment: Google says there is also `window.opener` for popups.